# Digit sum equals 44 of a squared number

Tags: proof-verification, recreational-mathematics, decimal-expansion

Is there a whole number $x$ such that the sum of the digits of $x^2$ equals 44?

I would like someone to tell me if my thoughts are correct.

The remainder of a number a divided with 9 is the same as the remainder of the sum of digits of a divided with 9.

According to that we have:

$\frac{x^2}{9}=d+r$

and

$\frac{44}{9}=d_1+r$

If there existed such a whole number $x$ then $d_1$ would be a whole number, which it is not.
So I think the answer should be no.

Comment: If the remainder of $a$ when divided by $9$ is, let's say $8$, then we have that $\frac{a-8}{9}$ is an integer, not that $\frac a9$ is done integer plus $8$. Back to the problem, have you heard about modular arithmetic?

Comment: No I haven't but I will have a look now

Comment: Hint: knowing the sum of the digits, what can you tell about the remainder when you divide $x^2$ by $9$?

Comment: It's basically arithmetic on remainders when divided by some number $n$. It's especially powerful when $n$ is a prime, but in this case $n=9$ would be the most straight-forward.

Comment: @mark bennet no idea, can you elaborate

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If the sum of the digits of $x^2$ is $44$, then $x^2$ has remainder $2$ on division by $3$. This is impossible.

**Remark:** Your proposed argument is not correct. Please note that one could use exactly the same argument to "show" that the sum of the digits of $x^2$ cannot be $7$. But it can be: the sum of the digits of $16$ is $7$.

Comment: Could you please explain why it is impossible to have remainder 2 by division by 3

Comment: @Nash You only need to check the cases: $x=0,1,2 \pmod 3$

Comment: A number $x$ is of the shape $3k$, $3k+1$, or $3k+2$. The square of $3k$ has remainder $0$ on division by $3$. The square of $3k+1$ is $9k^2+6k+1$, that is, $3(3k^2+2k)+1$, remainder $1$. The square of $3k+2$ is $9k^2+12k+4$, that is, $3(3k^2+4k+1)+1$, remainder $1$. In  no case do we get remainder $2$. (Congruence notation would make the above calculations simpler.)

Answer (score 1):

You would write $\dfrac{x^2}{9} = d + \dfrac {44}9$, which gives you
$x^2 = 9d + 44$. Since $\dfrac{44}9 = 4 + \dfrac 89$, you could combine the two and get $x^2 = 9(d+4) + 8$. None of these seem to imply any contradictions.

The sum of the digits of $0$ through $8$ squared are

```
 0 → 0
 1 → 1
 2 → 4
 3 → 9
 4 → 16 → 7
 5 → 25 → 7
 6 → 36 → 9
 7 → 49 → 13 → 4
 8 → 64 → 10 → 1
```

Every positive integer is of the form $9a + b$ where $0 \le b \le 8$.

It follows that, if you keep summing the digits of $x^2$ until you get just one digit, that digit is going to have to be $0, 1, 4, 9, $ or $7$. the sum will never be $44$, whose digits sum to $8$.